# Error while updating a firestore doc in an AppState listener

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am developing my Expo app with Firebase Firestore, and I would like to perform a reading and a writing per session. When the user opens the app, it reads his document and saves it locally, while when he gets out the app he passes the new document to the firestore. My problem is I do not know when and how to write the new document.

I tried detecting when the App goes background with AppState, and then calling the writing function, but on Android the async functions seem to be executed only after the device returns in foreground.

Is there a way to solve my AppState problem? Or do you suggest me another way?